# Compiler error: Expected identifier or '('

Tags: objective-c

Here is my code for reference. It's just one error:

```
{ /*** Expected identifier or '(' ***/
    sunanimation.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imagedNamed:@"Sun 1.png"],
                                    [UIImage imagedNamed:@"Sun 2.png"],
                                    [UIImage imagedNamed:@"Sun 3.png"],
                                    [UIImage imagedNamed:@"Sun 4.png"],
                                    [UIImage imagedNamed:@"Sun 5.png"],
                                    [UIImage imagedNamed:@"Sun 6.png"], nil];
    //always need nil

    [sunanimation setAnimationRepeatCount:90];
    //how many times it repeats
    [sunanimation setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    //how many seconds each animation lasts

    [sunanimation startAnimating];
    //begins the animation

}
```

Comment: The code starts above the grayed area.

Comment: Have you declared `sunanimation` somewhere?

Comment: Its `imageNamed` not `imagedNamed`

Comment: The problem is caused before the code you posted. We need to see more context to offer any help.

Comment: `rmaddy` is correct the issue isn't in this method. Please share all the code exactly how it is in your .m we need to know everything.

Answer (score 1):

You got a Typo man. The problem is `imagedNamed`, a wrong keyword.

Kindly use `[UIImage imageNamed:@"Sun 1.png"]`